# How to save a UUID as binary(16) in java

Tags: java, mysql, primary-key, uuid, sql2o

I have a table TestTable with columns ID as binary(16) and name as varchar(50)

I've been trying to store an ordered UUID as PK like in this article [Store UUID in an optimized way](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/)

I see the UUID is saved in database as HEX (blob)

So I want to save this ID from java but I am getting this error

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ID' at row 1

I am currently using the library sql2o to interact with mysql

So basically this is my code

```
String suuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String partial_id = suuid.substring(14,18) + suuid.substring(9, 13) + suuid.substring(0, 8) + suuid.substring(19, 23) + suuid.substring(24)
String final_id = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, partial_id.getBytes()));
con.createQuery("INSERT INTO TestTable(ID, Name) VALUES(:id, :name)")
        .addParameter("id", final_id)
        .addParameter("name", "test1").executeUpdate();
```

The partial id should be something like this **11d8eebc58e0a7d796690800200c9a66**

I tried this statement in mysql without issue

```
insert into testtable(id, name) values(UNHEX(CONCAT(SUBSTR(uuid(), 15, 4),SUBSTR(uuid(), 10, 4),SUBSTR(uuid(), 1, 8),SUBSTR(uuid(), 20, 4),SUBSTR(uuid(), 25))), 'Test2');
```

But I got the same error when I remove the unhex function. So how can I send the correct ID from Java to mysql?

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem inspired on the answer of [David Ehrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40297651/2532403). But in my case I used the HexUtils from tomcat to transform my sorted UUID string into bytes[]:

```
byte[] final_id = HexUtils.fromHexString(partial_id);
```

Comment: The immediate cause of the error is that `final_id` is 64 characters wide, but the column only holds 16 bits.

Comment: **NOTE**: The approach mentioned here **cannot be used with Java** as the link is about MySQL-UUID (UUID version 1) which isn't the same as Java `UUID.randomUUID()` (produces UUID version 4).

Version 1 is timestamp based which is the reason for reordering (and possibly truncating the MAC address). It needs a quite precise lookup of the time (nanoseconds).
Version 4 is a completely random number, where **reordering has no use at all** and you should not snip parts, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier.

Storing type 4 as `byte[16]` stays a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try storing it as bytes:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes)
        .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
        .putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
        .putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

con.createQuery("INSERT INTO TestTable(ID, Name) VALUES(:id, :name)")
    .addParameter("id", uuidBytes)
    .addParameter("name", "test1").executeUpdate();
```

A bit of an explanation: your table is using BINARY(16), so serializing UUID as its raw bytes is a really straightforward approach. UUIDs are essentially 128-bit ints with a few reserved bits, so this code writes it out as a big-endian 128-bit int. The ByteBuffer is just an easy way to turn two longs into a byte array.

Now in practice, all the conversion effort and headaches won't be worth the 20 bytes you save per row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very appreciated. Can you explain a bit your code?  The code of the article suggests to rearrange the UUID removing the hyphens and sorting the segments as let's say ID = 1d8eebc58e0a7d7, the ByteBuffer should have the same idea?

Comment: I successfully saved the record but I did this query mysql: select hex(id), length(hex(id)), name from testtable; and I got this as ID "626E316000774FE1A3E14BBD99E74EB0" So that's not the format that I was expecting as in the question. It should be something like this 1d8eebc58e0a7d7

Comment: @MaximusDecimus 16 bytes is 32 hex digits, so why would you expect `1d8eebc58e0a7d7`, which is only 15 digits?

Comment: Sorry I copied the value wrongly. 11d8eebc58e0a7d796690800200c9a66

Comment: And the other way around: `ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidBytes); UUID uuid = new UUID(buf.getLong(), buf.getLong())`.

Comment: What is the significance of `.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)`?